# ffmpeg avformat_open_input always returns "Protocol not found" rv=(-1330794744)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, ffmpeg

Trying to get ffmpeg working in Visual Studio 2010. So far all ffmpeg headers and libs are loaded, no error or warning occurs.

```
avcodec_register_all();
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
char errbuf[256];
pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
int rv = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, "myfile.ext", NULL, NULL);
if (rv!=0){                              
    av_strerror(rv, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
}
```

The problem is, avformat_open_input always returning -1330794744 (errbuf="Protocol not found"). Tried x86 & x64 headers and libs on 32bit XP and 64bit W7. Whatever I put for "myfile.ext" (tried "file1.avi", "file=c:\file1.avi", "http://www.someweb.com/file1.avi", and even empty char* "") response is always "Protocol not found". Any ideas?

Comment: Have you solved the problem yet?

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem. The correct initialization is

```
av_register_all();
```

Comment: Hi,  I am trying to do a sample chrome plugin, using ffmpeg. I have the same issue, I called av_register_all() , but no hope.

Comment: @GeorgeVarghese I am experiencing the same. Have you solved it?

Comment: Haha, nice "have you solved the problem?" ping-pong XD .Well,at least in my case it was wroing ffmpeg build config where some of the protocols were missing.

Comment: Ohh sorry for the late reply. No , issue is still exists.

Comment: @TOP In my case the problem was caused because I had the same library already in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH (DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on mac) and it was of a different version, which caused for this problem. I spent like an hour trying to figure out why it works on Linux and Android but not on macOS, time I could have spent more efficiently, sometimes life sucks :( BTW: `av_register_all` is now deprecated and this answer will not help

Answer (score 2):

I hope that his can help someone. Since I had the same problem where my code worked on Android and Linux but not on macOS and since `av_register_all` is now deprecated (for [FFMpeg version > 4.0](https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial/issues/29)) the answer from *discomurray* didn't solve the problem for me.

The reason why it didn't work in my case was that I already had **libavformat** installed on my system which was under `/usr/local/lib/` and unfortunately it was not configured correctly for my case (or mismatched the version compared to one I compiled myself).

What I did is, I added the path to my build to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (macOS) before executing the command:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Users/xxx/projects/FFmpeg/libavformat
```

On linux you can do the same with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

```
try to change file path 
"/home/user/video.mp4" -> "file:/home/usr/video.mp4"
```

and may you should escape ':' char unless protocol
check this link [ffmpeg-protocols#file](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#file)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I didn't know that. I'm a newbie... Thanks for comment :)